# Using multipledispatch with a "catch all" method signature

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have recently become acquainted with the [`multipledispatch` module](http://multiple-dispatch.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), and it's pretty nifty. I can do things like this, for example:

```
from multipledispatch import dispatch

class cls():
    @dispatch(object)
    def __init__(self, obj):
        #construct a cls instance using obj#
    @dispatch(int, int)
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        #construct a cls instance using x and y#
```

I would like to know if `multipledispatch.dispatch` has a way to add a method at the end that catches any and all arguments.  I have tried looking through the documentation but don't see a way to do that.

What I am trying to do is add a final version of `__init__` with the signature of `(self, *args, **kwargs)` so that I can have custom behavior for all other argument combinations not accounted for in previous `@dispatch` decorated versions. I have tried doing something like the following, but it only works when there are no arguments supplied:

```
class cls():
    @dispatch(object)
    def __init__(self, obj):
        #construct a cls instance using obj#
    @dispatch()
    #this version of __init__only get called when zero arguments supplied
    #would like it to be called for all argument combinations not matching those
    #accounted for above
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise TypeError("cls instance cannot be constructed from supplied arguments.")
```

Comment: OP is talking about [this library](http://multiple-dispatch.readthedocs.org), I think.

Comment: It looks like they're still [figuring out](https://github.com/mrocklin/multipledispatch/issues/2) how to support `*args`.

Comment: @Kevin thanks. Guess I'll be sticking to the overload module instead for now.